# How to extract the value related to a label cell from a html table using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="data-table data-table_detailed">
     <div class="cell">
         <div class="cell_label"> Label1 </div>
         <div class="cell_value"> Value2 </div>
    <div class="cell">
         <div class="cell_label"> Label2 </div>
         <div class="cell_value"> Value2 </div>
    <div class="cell">
         <div class="cell_label"> Label3 </div>
         <div class="cell_value"> Value3 </div>
```

and I would like to use BeautifulSoup to get the value related to *Label2*.

I do the following

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
datatable = soup.find(class_="data-table data-table_detailed")
datatable.find_all(class_="cell_label") #to get the list of labels
```

But how can I get the value that is in cell of the label *Label2*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_next_sibling`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
datatable = soup.find(class_="data-table data-table_detailed")
cell_labels = datatable.find_all(class_="cell_label") #to get the list of labels

for cell_label in cell_labels:
    if "Label2" in cell_label.text:
        print(cell_label.find_next_sibling("div", {"class": "cell_value"}).text)

# results
 Value2
```

Comment: Hi @arthurim does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 0):

It will be more easy using the [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method (css selectors):

```
value_tag = soup.select('.data-table.data-table_detailed .cell_value')[1] # Here you got your second value `tag`
text = value_tag.get_text() # Return the text inside your value element
```

Comment: I think the OP is after the text in the "value" `<div>`, i.e. `Value2` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This code will find the first `<div>` tag in the document with class `cell_label` in which the (stripped) contents is `Label2`:

```
>>> soup.find('div', class_='cell_label', string=lambda s: s.strip() == 'Label2').find_next_sibling().string
u' Value2 '
```

If you need to find only the `<div>` contained in the first `<div class="data-table data-table_detailed">`:

```
>>> table = soup.find(class_="data-table data-table_detailed")
>>> table.find('div', class_='cell_label', string=lambda s: s.strip() == 'Label2').find_next_sibling().string
u' Value2 '
```